# Mysql left join multiple columns on same column

Tags: mysql

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish, is I want the `test.zfirewallaudit.src_ip` AND `test.zfirewallaudit.dst_ip` fields to join on the `inventory.dns_zones.ip` column, so i can basically have an accurate hostname (`inventory.dns_zones.subdomain`) for `test.zfirewallaudit.src_ip` AND `test.zfirewallaudit.dst_ip`. so basically I want a column for src_ip subdomain and a column for dst_ip subdomain.

```
SELECT test.zfirewallaudit.src_ip, 
test.zfirewallaudit.src_zone, 
test.zfirewallaudit.dst_ip, 
test.zfirewallaudit.dst_zone, 
test.zfirewallaudit.dst_port, 
test.zfirewallaudit.rulename, 
test.zfirewallaudit.application,
inventory.dns_zones.subdomain
FROM test.zfirewallaudit LEFT JOIN inventory.dns_zones ON zfirewallaudit.src_ip = inventory.dns_zones.ip OR zfirewallaudit.dst_ip = inventory.dns_zones.ip LIMIT 10;
```

Problem is, I need the `inventory.dns_zones.subdomain` for both the `test.zfirewallaudit.src_ip` and `...dst_ip` values. The current query only gives me 1 `subdomain` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on `inventory.dns_zones` twice, once for the src and once for the dst:

```
SELECT test.zfirewallaudit.src_ip, 
test.zfirewallaudit.src_zone, 
test.zfirewallaudit.dst_ip, 
test.zfirewallaudit.dst_zone, 
test.zfirewallaudit.dst_port, 
test.zfirewallaudit.rulename, 
test.zfirewallaudit.application,
dns_zones_src.subdomain,
dns_zones_dst.subdomain
FROM test.zfirewallaudit
LEFT JOIN inventory.dns_zones AS dns_zones_src ON ( zfirewallaudit.src_ip = dns_zones_src.ip )
LEFT JOIN inventory.dns_zones AS dns_zones_dst ON ( zfirewallaudit.dst_ip = dns_zones_dst.ip )
LIMIT 10;
```